# Did Weyoun and Brunt ever meet (EU)

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Brunt the Ferengi, and Weyoun the Vorta were two important recurring characters in Star Trek: Deep Space 9, played by the same actor Jeffery Combs.

They never met onscreen during the run of the TV show. Both characters appeared in [one episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Dogs_of_War_(episode)), but they didn't meet.

A lot of people have thought this was a missed opportunity, and they should have been an episode where they met.

Were there any EU comics/ novels/ other where they did meet, and have some plot-significant interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hard as it is to prove a negative, and subject to the proviso that there may be something around the corner to prove this answer wrong, there appear to be no EU novels, comics or licenced short stories in which both Brunt and Weyoun (or Shran, Tiron, Kevin Mulkahey, Suldok, Penk or Krem, for that matter) meet or take a significant part.

Sorry.